# What is the meaning of this C++ code

Tags: c++

I'll be greateful if someone please tell me what is the meaning of this line of C++ code, what's it doing?

```
temp = ((uchar*) matimg.data + i)[j];
```

in this block of code

```
int rows =(int) height;
int cols =(int) width;
Mat matimg(img);

vector<vector<double> > vec1(rows, vector<double>(cols));
int k =1;
for (int i=0; i < rows; i++) {
    for (int j =0; j < cols; j++){
        unsigned char temp;
        temp = ((uchar*) matimg.data + i)[j];
        vec1[i][j] = (double) temp;
    }

}
```

P.S. I don't speak C++, I speak C#

Comment: Is there a specific part of it that you don't understand? E.g. do you understand multiplication, addition, and array indexing, or do you need that explained to you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's overlaying the 1D `matimg.data` array with a number of `matimg.step`-spaced 2D matrices, and then virtually indexing it at `(j, k)`.

Comment: "It's overlaying the 1D matimg.data array with a number of matimg.step" what is the meaning of this part? or could you please tell me how could I write that single line of code in C#?

Comment: If the data structures are the same then you'd write it almost exactly the same way. Just make sure you have a byte array.

Comment: Thank you! I tried that, but I got error, Operator '+' cannot be applied to operands of type 'int[]' and 'int', That's OK I'll figure it out somehow.

Answer (score 0):

If it helps, you can also rewrite this expression as

```
((uchar*) matimg.data)[ i * matimg.step + j * matimg.elemSize() + k ]
```

The original formulation is clearer as to its intent in the data access, but maybe this formulation is clearer to demonstrate how you’d do the C# rewrite.